# How do I import Opensearch from opensearchpy?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, opensearch

new to the community here. I didn't find this problem discussed, so I'm probably missing something super obvious. Thanks!

Python Code snippet:

```py
import botocore
import time
import os
import os.path
import sys
import io
import urllib.parse
import json
import base64

from io import BytesIO
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

from s3transfer.manager import TransferManager
from trp import Document
```

[error code from lambda while using s3 put test scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8rM9.png)

Comment: hmm, looks like the error makes sense. at least, `opensearchpy` is not a builtin module that i recognize.

Comment: you'll need to zip up the dependencies and deploy the zip file to lambda. essentially, lambda needs to see an `opensearchpy` folder at the root level of your code structure, otherwise the import should result in an error as lambda doesn't have it (note that libs like `botocore` are already built into lambda)

Comment: opensearchpy is supposed to be the successor to elasticsearch at aws. This is the dev guide, but I couldn't find anything actionable: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/opensearch-service-dg.pdf

Comment: rv.kvetch was right - needed the layer in lambda. I had the zip file directory structure wrong and needed to include dependent libraries
1. do a pip install to a target directory
2. put those folders/files into a python folder
3. zip the python folder, rename, upload to lambda layer

Answer (score 3):

commented above, but to answer.

1. create a layer directory with a 'python' folder
2. install library into that python folder

   $ py -m pip install opensearch-py --target lambda-layer/python/
3. zip the python folder and re-name to something relevant (opensearch-py.1.0.0.zip)
4. create layer in lambda, upload zip file
5. add layer to lambda function
6. victory

there's a bunch of info out there with differing file directory structures for layers, but the [fine folks at amazon wrote it down](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). I just missed the need to have all the dependent collateral libraries included in the zip for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-py/blob/main/USER_GUIDE.md:

```
pip install opensearch-py
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install opensearch-py
```

Then import it like any other module:

```
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch
```